How to Import & Modify a Python module file in Collab
Basically I mounted my google drive. Uploaded & created a module file within my google drive.
The first function I created worked but all subsequent modifications to the module file seemed to cause import errors.
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

I create using file new or upload a file to drive. Here is the file.
Here is datautils.py the module file that in MyDrive
#datautils.py
import datetime

def get_the_current_time():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_time = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return formatted_time

print(get_current_time())

Another cell I import:
 import sys
 sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive')

 from timeutils import get_the_current_time

 get_the_current_time() # works 

Everything works fine, but now I try defining another function
#datautils.py
import datetime

def get_the_current_time():
  current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
  formatted_time = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  return formatted_time
def get_the_current_time2():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_time = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return formatted_time

print(get_current_time())

Now its not going to work if I try to import get_the_current_time2 although get_the_current_time still works. I get import module not found etc? What is the problem?
I tried several tutorials on this. For example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-custom-modules-in-google-colab/
And they all work up to a point but once there is any modification to the custom module file from within colab it can no longer find either the module or the functions athough it can still import the function that was defined in the module file initially. I also do have init.py in all directories.
Is this due to the colab file editor? Do I need to install another editor for this to work? ie https://peter-jp-xie.medium.com/develop-colab-notebooks-with-visual-studio-code-de830dde9baa

Note This question has been sort of answered before on stack overflow, but not the part about modifying the imported module file within google collab. There is a comment by someone that google collab adds meta data that prevents reading the module when its edited. And suggestions about using another editor. I want clarification on what the issues is and solution for it.

After playing around with it a bit more I got the one module file to work. But when I create a new module python notebook and module I have the import problem again.

I don't know if I understand problem but normally Python remember already imported modules and it doesn't import it again. It needs to run code again - normally on desctop it needs to run script again, on Colab it may need to reset all code in Colab (restart kernel). If you want to run new module without restarting all code then you may need to use importlib.reload(timeutils)

ok that sounds right. @furas

so import importlib for module in sys.modules.values():     importlib.reload(module)  might work inside the notebook cell before importing the module?

Also do you recommend setting up VS Code with Colab?

frankly, I don't know what you means. I use Colab only in web browser without using any other editor or IDE. If you means to use VS Code to create files which later you will use in Colab then ... do whatever you like. It doesn't matter what IDE/editor you will use - Colab doesn't care of it, and it will always need to reload all code when you change something in module.

Ok, is there a good way to debug python code within Colab? Frankly I find it cumbersome to use the browser.  Scrolling up and down cells etc. Maybe I am using the wrong browser with colab but I find navigating/scrolling to be very cumbersome.

I never used Colab to import module/file which I modify at the same time. And if code doesn't need TPU  then I don't use Colab at all but I use normal text editor (or IDE) and I run it on local computer. And it always start all code from beginning so it doesn't make problem when I change something in other file.

if you made modifications in timeutils then you may need only importlib.reload(timeutils) after modifications (and only once import importlib). You don't have to reload other modules.

ok, I see. Thanks
